# cellForItemAtIndexPath not being called, unclear as to why

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uicollectionview

I've read a few other questions on this that the problem related to the size of the CollectionView. I've tried adjusting the size as recommended in those answers, but none of them were working. I'm using a NSFetchedResultsController which convolutes it for me as well (I'm wondering if it has something to do with it not firing).

Anyways, the real problem is I have no content appearing for my UICollectionView.  There are no errors at runtime, simply a blank screen. I'm working in Swift (obviously).

Here is my code from the ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

private let reuseIdentifier = "Family"
private var selectedFirstName:String = "Blank"
private var selectedLastName:String = "Blank"
private var selectedNumber:String = "Blank"
private var selectedEmail:String = "Blank"

class FamilyViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

var coreDataStack: CoreDataStack!
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController!

@IBOutlet var familyCollectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //1
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Family")

    let firstNameSort =
    NSSortDescriptor(key: "firstName", ascending: true)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [firstNameSort]

    //2
    self.coreDataStack = CoreDataStack() 
    fetchedResultsController =
        NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
            managedObjectContext: coreDataStack.context,
            sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
            cacheName: nil)

    fetchedResultsController.delegate = CollectionViewFetchedResultsControllerDelegate(collectionView: familyCollectionView)

    //3
    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}


func configureCell(cell: FamilyCCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath) { let family = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Family

    cell.firstNameLabel.text = family.firstName
    print("configureCell ran")

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    print("numberOfSectionsInCollectionView ran")
    return fetchedResultsController.sections!.count
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    let sectionInfo = fetchedResultsController.sections![section]
    print("numberOfItemsInSection ran")
    return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FamilyCCell

    print("cellForItemAtIndexPath ran")
    configureCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)

    return cell
}




override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "showDetail") {
        let detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ContactViewController

        print("prepareForSegue ran")
        detailVC.detailFirstName = selectedFirstName
        detailVC.detailLastName = selectedLastName
        detailVC.detailNumber = selectedNumber
        detailVC.detailEmail = selectedEmail
    }
}
}

extension FamilyViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("didSelectItemAtIndexPath ran")
    collectionView.delegate = self

    let family = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Family

    selectedFirstName = family.firstName!
    selectedLastName = family.lastName!
    selectedNumber = family.phone!
    selectedEmail = family.email!
    coreDataStack.saveContext()
}
}


class CollectionViewFetchedResultsControllerDelegate: NSObject, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

// MARK: Properties

private let collectionView: UICollectionView
private var blockOperations: [NSBlockOperation] = []

// MARK: Init

init(collectionView: UICollectionView) {
    self.collectionView = collectionView
}

// MARK: Deinit

deinit {
    blockOperations.forEach { $0.cancel() }
    blockOperations.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
}

// MARK: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    blockOperations.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    switch type {

    case .Insert:
        guard let newIndexPath = newIndexPath else { return }
        let op = NSBlockOperation { [weak self] in self?.collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath]) }
        blockOperations.append(op)

    case .Update:
        guard let newIndexPath = newIndexPath else { return }
        let op = NSBlockOperation { [weak self] in self?.collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath]) }
        blockOperations.append(op)

    case .Move:
        guard let indexPath = indexPath else { return }
        guard let newIndexPath = newIndexPath else { return }
        let op = NSBlockOperation { [weak self] in self?.collectionView.moveItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, toIndexPath: newIndexPath) }
        blockOperations.append(op)

    case .Delete:
        guard let indexPath = indexPath else { return }
        let op = NSBlockOperation { [weak self] in self?.collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath]) }
        blockOperations.append(op)

    }
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {

    switch type {

    case .Insert:
        let op = NSBlockOperation { [weak self] in self?.collectionView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex)) }
        blockOperations.append(op)

    case .Update:
        let op = NSBlockOperation { [weak self] in self?.collectionView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex)) }
        blockOperations.append(op)

    case .Delete:
        let op = NSBlockOperation { [weak self] in self?.collectionView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex)) }
        blockOperations.append(op)

    default: break

    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
        self.blockOperations.forEach { $0.start() }
        }, completion: { finished in
            self.blockOperations.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    })
}
}
```

I have print statements confirming that the cellForItemAtIndexPath is not running. Any ideas? I realize this is quite specific and I gave a crap ton of code, just not quite sure where the error could be coming from. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: I believe I've done that. I've control-clicked them within the storyboard and connected the collectionView to the Datasource/Delegate. Anything with the viewcontroller code I'd need to hook up there? I didn't think so but I could definitely be mistaken.

Comment: are you returning nonzero number of sections and items?

Comment: I am querying the NSFetchedResultsController for the section count, so it should be returning a nonzero number.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if it has something to do with the connection I have set up with CoreData. I'm going to look into that for the next bit and cycle back here to add info if I find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure...you Confirm UICollectionViewDelegate protocol methods.
set `collectionview.delegate = self`

`collectionview.datasource = self`

Comment: While this would typically be it, it isn't fixing this code. I have them hooked up already.

Comment: Just to clarify to anyone reading this later, I changed my code to not reference a "CoreDataStack." Instead, I simply created a NSObject variable within this viewController and was able to get it to work that way. I'm accepting this answer as typically, this would be the issue (delegate/datasource not hooked up).

Answer (score 0):

in the collection view datasource for the methods `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` return 1 and in `collectionViewNumberOfCellsForSection` return the number of cells you want to display

to clarify on tableview or a collection view a "section" is a group of related things where as a cell (or row for tableview) are the actual things you want to display - when you do not override the amount of cells required it will return 0 for all sections

(ill check the exact method signatures in the morning and edit if they are slightly off)

Answer (score 0):

Write it:

```
class FamilyViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate{
```

and write these two lines in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
familyCollectionView.delegate = self
```

```
familyCollectionView.datasource = self
```